# How can I run watch changes in asynchronous way NodeJS Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, mongoose

For the past 2 days I have been struggling on this thing. I want to watch for changes on particular collection. All of the logic for these changes is in asynchronous way. I tried to make the EventEmitter callback function to be asynchronous but still works in synchronous manner.

Pseudo code example:

```
const someLogicFunction1 = async () => {
   // some logic here
}

const someLogicFunction2 = async () => {
   // some logic here
}

const collectionEventEmitter = Collection.watch();

collectionEventEmitter.on('change', async (change) => {
  await someLogicFunction1();
  await someLogicFunction2(); // has to wait for first function to finish
});
```

As I explained above I tried this approach but still runs synchronously. The second function usually has to wait for the first function to finish its task in order for the whole code to be properly working.

EDIT:
From what I have found it seems that the callback function firstly gets all this "change" parameter event objects and then executes the code. What I need actually is to execute the code for every "change" event parameter - not for all of them at once.

Comment: Then why do you use async/await if you want your code to be asynchronous?? Async/await is used to make your async code synchronous.

Comment: @Molda Maybe I did not explain myself well. These logic functions are supposed to be asynchronous, otherwise none of the code is working as expected. The problem that I have is only on this event emitter that executes the functions simultaneously without actually waiting the result of the first one.

Comment: Well the `someLogicFunction1` should return a promise which should be resolved once all the work in it is done. It is impossible to help without seeing the code in that function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to make `someLogicFunction1()` returning a promise and calling `someLogicFunction2();` in then of first function, like this:

```
await someLogicFunction1()
  .then(function(){
    someLogicFunction2();
});
```

You just need to modify `someLogicFunction1();` like this:

```
someLogicFunction1( )
{
  return new Promise( async function( resolve, reject ) {
    // Do your stuff here
  }); // eo promise
}
```

Don't forget to `resolve()` in `someLogicFunction1` function.

```
resolve();
```

You can also `reject()` in `someLogicFunction1` and catch the error when you call this function.

```
reject();
```

You can pass an argument to resolve and reject and get it in your call.

Comment: I tried it, but still does not work. Otherwise one thing that I found is that this "change" parameter of the event emitter is only one object usually, but it executes the other part of the code after getting or looping through all the event objects event though it an async function.

Comment: Can you precise "still does not work" what's the problem?

Comment: Well, it was mistake on my side. My logic in these functions was a bit off. That is why it was not working again. But right now everything works as expected with your code. Thank you very much for your answer! :)